# Le futur ou le futur antérieur?

Tags: concordance-des-temps, futur, futur-simple, futur-proche

J'hésite entre la sélection du temps approprié afin d’expliquer deux actions dans le futur. Voici quelques exemples:

1.
A) je vous enverrai ce document dès que je le recevrai.
B) je vous enverrai ce document dès que (quand) je l’aurai reçu.

2.
A) Quand je reviendrai de vacances, nous en parlerons.
B) Quand je serai revenu de vacances, nous en parlerons.

3.
A) Quand tu rentreras chez toi, elle partira.
B) Lorsque tu rentreras chez toi, elle sera déjà partie.

Ici, dans chaque cas, j’ai utilisé soit (A) deux fois le futur  ou soit (B) le futur + le futur antérieur. Pourriez-vous préciser quelle est la différence (dans la perception de ces phrases) entre le deux constructions ? Serait-il possible d’y utiliser également le futur proche ou le conditionnel ?

Comment: Les 2 phrases de la proposition 3 n'ont pas le même sens: dans la première la personne n'est pas encore partie, dans la second, elle est déjà partie.

Answer (score 3):

Le futur désigne le temps durant lequel l'action se produit :

> Quand je reviendrai de vacances, nous en parlerons. (Au moment où je rentre de vacances)

Le futur antérieur désigne une période de temps située après que l'action se soit produite:

> Quand je serai revenu de vacances, nous en parlerons. (A un moment après que je sois rentré de vacances)

Comment: Merci! Et puis-je utiliser le conditionnel dans cette phrase :   Quand je serais revenu de vacances, nous en parlerions  ?

Comment: Non, dans ce cas il faut utiliser l'imparfait pour la condition, puis le conditionnel pour la réalisation. Exemple: Si je rentrais de vacances, nous en parlerions.

Comment: D’accord, merci encore ! Et finalement quelle serait donc la différence si j’utilisais plutôt le présent dans mon example : « nous en parlerons quand je reviens de vacances » , « je vous l’enverrai dès que je trouve une possibilité » ?

Answer (score 2):

Le futur antérieur permet de combiner deux instants distincts, contrairement au futur simple, qui place l'action en un seul instant défini dans la proposition pivot:

1. *Je te rendrai ton livre quand tu viendras chez moi.*

Reprenons maintenant un exemple cité plus haut:

2. *J'aurai déjà mangé quand tu reviendras de ton cours de danse.*

Dans la phrase 1, la proposition "*je te rendrai*" est **simultanée** de l'instant défini par "*quand tu viendras*": ce "*quand*" désigne le temps unique dans lequel se déroulent les 2 propositions de la phrase.

Dans la phrase 2, l'instant de référence est défini par "*quand tu reviendras*". Lors de cet instant futur, le second événement ("*j'aurai déjà mangé*") se situera dans le passé, même s'il est aussi dans le futur à l'instant où  parle le locuteur, d'où son nom "futur ***antérieur***": l'événement est futur, mais sera passé quand sera atteint l'instant de référence: Les deux instants sont ici asynchrones, alors qu'ils sont synchrones dans le cas du futur simple.

Comment: Merci bien pour votre explication ! Serait-il possible d’affirmer donc que le futur antérieur pourrait être comme le futur dans le passé dans ce cas ?

Comment: Si vous reconsidérez mon explication ci-dessus, je pense que vous conviendrez qu'il s'agit plutôt d'un passé dans le futur que d'un futur dans le passé.

Answer (score 1):

**I** D'après [oqlf, Concordance des temps](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=concordance&id=1175), « [l]es règles de la concordance – appelée maintenant correspondance – des temps déterminent quel temps du verbe il convient d’employer en fonction du rapport temporel existant entre deux propositions, ou, le plus souvent, dans une subordonnée en fonction du temps employé dans la principale, et en fonction du sens de la phrase. Ainsi, le verbe de la subordonnée se met au présent, au futur ou au passé, selon que l’action de ce verbe se passe pendant, après ou avant celle du verbe de la principale ». « [Le futur antérieur](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=futur+ant%C3%A9rieur&btn_chercher=CHERCHER&id=4129) est […] employé […] couramment pour parler d'un fait futur qui sera achevé avant la réalisation d'un autre fait futur. Dans cet emploi, le verbe conjugué au futur antérieur est en relation avec un verbe au futur simple ».

Exemples tirés de l'OQLF:

- Quand tu auras terminé tes devoirs, tu pourras aller jouer avec tes amies. (*user LPH : pas de possibilité d'un futur dans ce cas-ci*)
- Elle ne sera satisfaite que lorsqu'elle aura trouvé la maison de ses rêves. (*user LPH :  possibilité d'un futur dans le présent cas parce que l'on peut se borner à ne considérer l'état d'être satisfait qu'au moment de la découverte et une quasi simultanéité est établie; cependant le futur antérieur est préférable pour marquer un état qui se prolongera.*)
- J'aurai déjà mangé quand tu reviendras de ton cours de danse.
- ([ref. 1](https://books.google.fr/books?id=hZBBdIz17NIC&pg=PA112&dq=%22nous+reviendrons%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXzqnLvajrAhWGyoUKHehpDrMQ6AEwBHoECCQQAg#v=onepage&q=%22nous%20reviendrons%22&f=false)) Eh bien ! croyez-moi, Dieu vous a déjà donné une grande et terrible leçon, nous ne reviendrons au calme, à la prospérité, que lorsque nous reviendrons sincèrement à l'observation des préceptes de la religion et lorsque nous reviendrons à (*user LPH : Il parait évident que l'on peut aussi dire « lorsque nous seront revenus. »*)
- ([ref. 2](https://books.google.fr/books?id=LCyRQ4LsqRcC&pg=PA106&dq=%22nous+reviendrons%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2jfWxv6jrAhUwzoUKHaItBX44ZBDoATBTegQILBAC#v=onepage&q=%22nous%20reviendrons%22&f=false))  Nous reviendrons après quand tu seras tranquille, Nous reprendrons alors (*user LPH : La subordonnée exprime un état, et comme cela doit se prolonger sur une certaine période la simultanéité semble impossible puisque le retour peut se faire au début de la période de tranquillité ou plus tard et même à la fin; il y a quand même simultanéité et de ce fait une impossibilité d'utiliser le futur antérieur; considérer combien l'emploi du futur antérieur  rendrait la phrase différente (tu auras été tranquille; quand tu auras été tranquille au moins une fois)*)
- ([ref.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=VogIYPdwtcYC&pg=PA144&dq=%22nous+reviendrons%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqwrKhwKjrAhVQ1BoKHaNMB_84yAEQ6AEwBnoECC8QAg#v=onepage&q=%22nous%20reviendrons%22&f=false) Nous reviendrons sur la période préopératoire lorsque nous aborderons la période opératoire concrète dans le chapitre 8 sur le développement cognitif des enfants de 3 à 5 ans.(*user LPH : Lauteur a choisi la simultanéité mais il est possible de choisir l'action de revenir en tant qu'action postérieure et donc d'utiliser le futur antérieur.*)

**II** L'utilisation du futur proche est concevable mais le conditionnel changerait le sens et ce n'est donc pas possible.

Dans « 1 » l'un ou l'autre des deux temps convient parce que l'action d'envoyer ne se prolonge pas sur une période bien longue, elle est très courte et bien qu'elle soit évidemment subséquente à l'action dans la subordonnée, on peut considérer les deux comme simultanées.
L'utilisation du présent comme futur proche est possible mais on doit le trouver dans les deux propositions.

- Je vous envoie ce document dès que je le reçois.
- Je vais vous envoyer ce document dès que je vais le recevoir.
- Je vais vous envoyer ce document dès que je le reçois.
- <s>Je vous envoie ce document dès que je vais le recevoir/dès que je le recevrai.</s>

Dans « 2 » il est presque toujours préférable d'utiliser le futur antérieur parce que l'action doit nécessairement s'étaler sur une période assez longue. Cependant on dit communément « Nous en parlerons lorsque je reviendrai de vacance. ».

- Nous allons en parler quand je reviens de vacances.
- Nous allons en parler quand je vais revenir de vacances.
- (*« Nous en parlons … » est une possibilité mais sujette à contexte ; on utilise plus volontiers les autres formes. L'explication de cela ne me vient pas à l'esprit ; par exemple il semblerait que lorsque la première personne du singulier ou la troisième personne est utilisée l'emploi du présent soit plus naturel (Je t'explique tout ça quand je reviens.) ;*)

Dans « 3 » le changement de temps contemplé n'est plus dans la subordonnée mais dans la principale; donc, utiliser l'un ou l'autre des deux temps ne peut pas conférer  la même idée.

La futur exprimé par l'auxiliaire « aller » au présent est utilisable dans ce cas-ci mais, semble-t-il, pas le présent. Dans ce cas aussi la raison de cela ne me vient pas à l'esprit et cette exception à l'usage pourrait n'être qu'une impression personnelle.

- Quand tu vas rentrer/rentreras chez toi elle va partir/partira.
- Quand tu va rentrer/rentreras chez toi elle va être (déjà) partie/sera (déjà) partie.

Comment: Un grand merci de votre réponse et ses examples ! Oui justement, c’était toujours pas évident pourquoi c’est possible parfois utiliser le présent (pas le futur proche) pour expliquer les choses qui se passes bientôt !  E.g:  je (vais envoyer) vous enverrai ce document dès que je le reçois...... Et enfin , dans votre example, il s’agissant du conditionnel : « quand tu auras terminé tes devoirs, tu pourrais aller jouer » , quelle sera la différence, si j’y utilise plutôt le futur ( ... tu pourra) ?

Comment: @MaîtreRenard « Quand tu auras terminé tes devoirs, tu pourrais aller jouer » ;  « tu pourrais » (conditionnel) signifie un certain nombre de chose que le contexte rend spécifiques; « il y a une possibilité, je ne m'oppose pas formellement à ce que tu ailles jouer », « tu pourras y aller si rien de spécial ne survient », « je te suggère d'aller jouer,  bien sûr si tu le veux . ». « Il s'agissant du conditionnel » est un anglicisme; la phrase qui contient cela est à revoir (plusieurs erreurs). On dit « possible **d**'utiliser » ; les choses qui se pass**ent**. (1/2)

Comment: @MaîtreRenard « …les choses qui se passent bientôt » : pas idiomatique : option de formulation idiomatique : « les choses qui se passent dans un futur proche », « les chose qui se passent à courte/brève échéance ». One more : « Un grand merci **pour** votre réponse » . (You welcome) (2/2)

Comment: Merci beaucoup! Et oui effectivement, je ne savais pas vraiment quelle serait la différence entre “merci de” et “merci pour” , puisque comme j’avais bien constaté, il y avait bcp d’utilisation de préposition “de” dans les phrases comme “je vous remercie de..” etc . Voilà !

Comment: @MaîtreRenard Je comprends ; nous sommes nombreux, les étudiants d'une langue étrangère, a nous être laissés prendre par des apparences de cette sorte et d'autres encore.